# Pushing array variable from inside array variable which has been created dynamically funtion

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push, create-function

I would like to have this array from

```
array(
'label'=> 'Guest Capacity',
'desc'  => 'Total capacity of Guests',
'id'    => 'vessel_guest_capacity',
'type'  => 'select',
'options' => array ( 
    1 => array ( 'label' => '1', 'value' => 1 ),
    2 => array ( 'label' => '2', 'value' => 2 ),
    3 => array ( 'label' => '3', 'value' => 3 ),
    )
);
```

from this function, what is wrong with that?

```
array(
    'label'=> 'Guest Capacity',
    'desc'  => 'Total capacity of Guests',
    'id'    => 'vessel_guest_capacity',
    'type'  => 'select',
    'options' => function() { for($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++){ if(!is_set($var)){ $var = array(); } $var[] = array ( 'label' => "$i", 'value' => $i ); } $this['options'] = $var; },
),
```

I tried with return but didn't have any luck.

Comment: You mention having 25 other arrays, that having one function for does not work. Can you share more information about the structure/requirements for them?

Comment: @sharf I have created https://eval.in/375350 in order to explain situation. This is unfinished array. I will going to add about 20 fields more to it.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh please check https://eval.in/375350 You will understand what I ment.